# libGDX: how to tell if shader log refers to frag or vert shader error

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glsl, shader, libgdx

After compiling a `ShaderProgram` if it doesn't compile I print the log.
However, I can't find a way to tell if the error is in the fragment or vertex shader.

Here I put an error in the frag shader:

```
0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER
```

This error is in the vert shader:

```
0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER
```

is there a way to show more detail about where the error is?

Looking at the Libgdx ShaderProgram source I couldn't seem to see one: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShaderProgram.html

Comment: Libgdx is just passing the log back from the underlying OpenGL driver,  its not compiling the shader itself.

Comment: well... obviously, but how can I get indication of which shader its just sent to the driver thats had an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but: You can add a blank line at the beginning of one of the two shaders. Then see if the line number for the error changes to determine which one it applies to.

Comment: yeah, I kinda thought I was being dumb using these kind of strategies but I notice that even in other languages / environments you encounter the same issue, you can only hope the Khronos group cotton on to this and improve error reporting for shaders! I'll accept your answer as the only voice of sanity!